# How many permutations of {1,2,...,n}.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

**How many permutations of {1,2,...,n} where n >=5 are there such that none of {1,2,3} are adjacent to one another?**

Example: the permutation (5,3,1,4,2) does not meet the condition described in the problem because 1 and 3 are in two adjacent places and the permutation (2,5,3,4,1) as well as (1,6,2,5,3,4) meets this condition.

Comment: count the ways to pick three non-adjacent positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving comment to answer:

First arrange the numbers $4,5,6,\dots,n$.

Next, pick a "hole" between those or to either side to place the $1$.  Then pick a different hole to place the $2$, etc...

> $(n-3)!\cdot (n-2)(n-3)(n-4)$

In general, the number of permutations of $1,2,3,\dots,k,\dots,n$ where none of $1,2,\dots,k$ are adjacent, the same approach works.

> $(n-k)!\cdot \frac{(n-k+1)!}{(n-2k+1)!}$

or better yet, using $a\frac{b}{~}$ to denote the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) $a\frac{b}{~}=\underbrace{a(a-1)(a-2)\cdots(a-b+1)}_{b~\text{terms}} = \frac{a!}{(a-b)!}$ this would be

> $(n-k)!\cdot (n-k+1)\frac{k}{~}$

Answer (score 2):

Consider $A$ representing a permutation of the elements $1,2,3$. Since the remaining $n-3$ elements may be permuted in $(n-3)!$ ways, the required number is $$n!-\binom{3}{2}2!(n-1)!+\binom{3}{3}3!(n-2)!$$ because of [the inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: Your result is off.  You should have $n!-\binom{3}{2}2!(n-\color{red}{1})!+\binom{3}{3}3!(n-\color{red}{2})!$ instead.  That being said, this approach is not recommended because it is harder to follow and the final expression used is quite unwieldy and requires much more calculation than necessary if we were to extend to asking for numbers $1,2,3,\dots,k$ to be non-adjacent.

Comment: Rectified. Thanks for the attention.